# CQRS Projections by consumer is not designed for API Portfolio Architecture?

Tags: c#, rest, api, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I don't understand how to make a generic API REST, (like recommendation, no specific API by consumer) in an API Portfolio, but and the other recommendation of CQRS that tell, make projections by consumers, and so an API (GET) by consumers.

I wish a simple solution, and in this case, how to avoid to make only one projection with everything inside.

It's the same problem. How to expose DDD Application Layer, via an API REST, because Applicaiton Layer should return the consumer want, to return only data need with specific format etc...

Thanks

Comment: Can you reformulate your question ? I try to help but do not understand the problem you are facing...

Comment: When you have complex application, like accounting service in microservices with many consumers of this service, should have one enpoint like GetContract, that return an agregate with all informations accounting, or should provide many enpoint with different projection, of accounting contract, most specific with end use case of consumer (like projections in CQRS). Because for the first solution, load large agregate with all possible calculation result need by the consumer or delegate the consumer to do this calculation is not good, but is more REST, reusability API target

Comment: Having one endpoint means all consumers have access to all the data.  So first you have to determine the credentials that are need to access data.  Seconds is all queries going to return same number of columns (views) or are you gong to have different views for different types of queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, REST is not a goal per se. Furthermore, it's [often believed](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/rest-api-design-resource-modeling) that resource-basednes of REST harms Domain-Driven Design.

As the article referred above states for your case it's perfectly fine to build customer-centric endpoints as in your case.

As for me, I do think that most developers strive to implement REST not because of it's resource-oriented but because it's stateless which facilitates horizontal scalability. And also because [stereotypical architecture](https://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/a-stereotypical-architecture/) is something that is easy to catch up.

P.S. Orignal spec states that [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) is required for REST API. Based on my experience I've never seen it implemented in any of those so-called "REST API", and I doubt you'll be the first. So you won't be implementing  REST API in a strcit definition of it anyways :)